# Boost's managed_shared_memory usage in between two processes (C and C++)

Tags: c++, c, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I am having a Design/Implementation issue with Boost `managed_shared_memory`.

### Problem

I have two processes: `Writer` and `Reader`.

- Here `Writer` is a C++ executable which is using boost to write in shared memory. Code snapshot for writing method:

  ```
  shm_controller.reset(new boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory( boost::interprocess::open_or_create, shmName, size));
  void * addr = shm_controller->allocate(size) ;
  shm_controller->deallocate(addr);
  ```

  Once I have addr pointer, I am using `memcpy` to write in SHM.
- On other hand I am having `Reader`, which is C executable. They both are communicating via message passing application. I wrote `Reader` code in such way:

  - `Writer` is passing address, which is stored in "addr" (from above code snapshot) to `Reader`.
  - Once `Reader` receive the address and size, I am using `memcpy` to write SHM data from `Reader`'s local variable.

> Note 1: (This `Reader` is not using any boost shm API, as it's C application )
>   Note 2: I validated address is same on `Writer` and `Reader` (after communication).

But `Reader`'s `memcpy` to read shm data is leading crash in my executable (`Reader`).

---

### Questions

1. Can we use `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory` in C ??
2. Is there any implementation problem in above section. (can't a `Reader` access shm of `Writer` via pointer)
3. Is there a way to solve this C and C++ limitation like any wrapper implementation etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q.** Can we use boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory in C ??

No. Technically, you can, of course (C is turing complete), but it's not supported.

> **Q.** Is there any implementation problem in above section. (can't a reader access shm of writer via pointer)

Yes, you cannot usefully pass a pointer from one process to another, because they have isolated address space.

> **Q.** Is there a way to solve this C and C++ limitation like any wrapper implementation etc.

The usual approach is to pass data among processes as part of the message. Use your message passing library (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html, http://zeromq.org/, etc.).

**Note**: *This also avoids trouble with synchronizing access to shared memory, that you haven't even talked about. This gives me the idea you didn't think of it*

The next best idea would be to use raw shm API on both sides and pass the *offset* into the shared-memory area across processes. You could still use BIP, if you limit yourself to e.g. [`shared_memory_object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.shared_memory_steps) and e.g. [`offset_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_region.mapped_region_address_mapping)

Comment: sehe >> [ No. Technically, you can, of course (C is turing complete), but it's not supported. ] --> So you mean to say there is no api from Boost but we can do it by some way. Could you please provide some more information on this other way ?                           You said [" raw shm API on both sides and pass the offset into the shared-memory area across processes. You could still use BIP" ]  --> BIP means boost. right ? How can i use boost because I have one process on C-lang.  Raw SHM-API, Could you please name some which can used between C and C++.

Comment: I mean you can duplicate Boost's code in C. Of course that's a stupid thing to do.

Comment: BIP does indeed mean Boost InterProcess

Comment: C++ is a superset of C. Use shmem API (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) in both C and C++.

Comment: ohk. I prepared API in C++ and boost but looks like I have to rework for C and SHM API. By the way Thanks Sehe... I will wait for sometime if nothing comes up I will mark your response as Answer and close it.

Comment: This Worked for me. Thanks.